# Css transsform scale child without affecting parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have this setup. On hover button will scale up. I want share-container to be scollable x if necessary (if the width becomes smaller than the amount of button that fit in one line).

If you hover the last button, you will get scoll appear and everthing jumps. How can I prevent scroll appear that while still leaving overflow-x: auto; on share-container if necessary ?

```css
.share-holder-inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.share-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #353b49;
}
.share-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.share-container button {
  width: 40px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="share-holder-inner">

  <div class="share-inner">

    <div class="share-container">

      <button type="button">1</button>
      <button type="button">2</button>
      <button type="button">3</button>
      <button type="button">4</button>
      <button type="button">5</button>
      <button type="button">6</button>
      <button type="button">7</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the parent share-holder-inner should become wider since there is still space around it.

Comment: I want to scroll x container which holds buttons obviously, but the out most parent should widen itself as much as it can before scoll on button container becomes necesary, is this possible?

Comment: Found a solution and removed my noise from comments.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `width: min-content` and `overflow: hidden;` for your first buttons parent element

```js
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const elCont = document.querySelector(".share-container");
  elCont.innerHTML += elCont.innerHTML;
})
```

```css
* { margin:0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.share-holder-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.share-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #353b49;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.share-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;      /* changed */
  width: min-content;    /* added */
}

.share-container button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.share-container button:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  scale: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="share-holder-inner">

  <div class="share-inner">

    <div class="share-container">

      <button type="button">1</button>
      <button type="button">2</button>
      <button type="button">3</button>
      <button type="button">4</button>
      <button type="button">5</button>
      <button type="button">6</button>
      <button type="button">7</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="test">ADD MORE BUTTONS</button>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, why isn't  `width: min-content;` taking into account the scaled size of the button?

Comment: because width `min-content` is a *set* width. Just like `width: 250px;`. If the width is not set the issue will occur, the parent trying to accommodate the scaled child. And `overflow: hidden;` should prevent such scaling issue to pop to the scrollable ancestor.